# Align mat-icon and img

Tags: css, angular-material

I want to align the bottom of my mat icon and that of the img next to it. I've tried multiple things, and this is what it currently looks like:
[image]

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
      <p class="triage"><mat-icon>assignment_ind</mat-icon></p>
      <p class="O2"><img src="../../assets/med_O2.png"></p>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.O2, .triage{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.container img {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}

.container mat-icon{
font-size: 60px;
width: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use line-height:

```
.container
{
line-height: 60px; //or what ever height your container is
}
```

Comment: Setting the line-height to 0px did the trick. Can you explain why?

Comment: Vertical-align: middle; is an funny one in that instead of height you have to use line-height: #sigh!

Answer (score 0):

Can you push mat-icon down with a little bit of margin or padding?

```
.container mat-icon{
    font-size: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

What about something like this?

```
<style>
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 65px;
    height: 100px;
}

p.triage {
    background: blue;
    width: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

p.O2 {
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
    <p class="triage"></p>
    <p class="O2"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I think this is possible, but I was hoping for a better solution.

Comment: Okay. So why not make container position relative. Make the children position absolute and give them both bottom: 0. Then give one left: 0 and the other right :0